# DocuSign Api - Sender View & EDIT_LOCK_ENVELOPE_LOCKED

Tags: docusignapi

Can anyone help.

I’m using the rest api to create an envelope, and then configure it using the api sender view call (/restapi/v2/accounts//envelopes//views/sender) to get the DocuSign UI.

Creating the envelope and viewing it the first time using sender view to bring up the docusign api works fine.

The problem occurs if instead of sending the envelope I click ‘save as draft’.  When I try to go back to the envelope and view it again using sender view I get the following error with http status of 400:

{
  "errorCode": "EDIT_LOCK_ENVELOPE_LOCKED",

"message": "The envelope is locked. The lock must be released before requesting the sender token for envelope, id = xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx."
}

The lock seems to wear off after time (apprx 20 mins). However after it wears off I can only view the item once, and then the lock is reapplied.

I can’t find anything in DocuSign api documentation that relates to this behaviour. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE (12/Feb/15): This error only happens on my demo account but not on production, so it seems like it's an account setting, but I can't figure out what/where the setting is.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is new documentation about this envelope locking feature and behavior in the February service pack (PDF) available here: https://www.docusign.com/support/releases.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The documentation does mention locking envelopes but it doesn't tell you how to prevent it. Any ideas?

Comment: The documentation also says:      "Note: API users are not required to use the new lock functionality. It is completely optional and current
customer applications will continue to function as-is."  This doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

We have a bug logged on our side where Save Draft isn't correctly releasing the lock on the envelope. We should have a fix for this issue in our DEMO environment soon. The locking feature is currently only "ON" in our DEMO environment but not in our Production environments while we find and fix potential issues such as the one identified here. More information about locking is in our February service pack (PDF) release notes available here: https://www.docusign.com/support/releases.